# About java war game

Tags: java, arraylist, computer-science

I am working on an assignment about a card game.
It says "You will have three Classes (Card, Deck and a Demo Class)".
I do not know how to write the rules as a code, and how to give 2 players half the deck of cards.

In this game, there are two players who each get half the deck of cards (26 cards each). Players, at the same time, flip
over the top card on their pile. The player who flips the higher value/rank card wins and captures both cards. The winning player adds
both cards to their pile of cards. If both players flip over cards with the same value/rank, then a "War" starts. When "War" is declared,
each player takes two additional cards from their piles; each player flips one card and leaves one card face-down. The player who flips
over the highest card wins the "War" pile (all six cards). So long as the flipped cards are the same value, each player continues to take
two additional cards from their piles, flipping one and leaving one face-down, until one card has a higher value and a winner of that
War is declared. After a War, the game resumes as normal (flipping and comparing one card at a time). A player loses when they run
out of cards; the game is then over.

Here is my code, I do not know what to do next. Hope someone can give me some ideas about this game.

```
public class Card {
    private int rank;
    private int suit;

    private static String[] suits = {"clubs","diamonds","hearts","spades"};
    public static final int CLUBS    = 0;
    public static final int DIAMONDS = 1;
    public static final int HEARTS   = 2;
    public static final int SPADES   = 3;

    private static String[] ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
             "9", "10", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"};
    public static final int JACK  = 11;
    public static final int QUEEN = 12;
    public static final int KING  = 13;
    public static final int ACE   = 14;

    /* Constructor
     * rank can be 2, 3, ..., 10, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE
     * suit can be CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES
     */
    public Card(int rank,int suit){
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }
      //returns the suit of the card
    public int getSuit(){
         return this.suit;
    }
    //returns the rank of card
    public int getRank(){
        return this.rank;
    }
    //determines which Card has the higher value
    public int compare(Card c){
        return rank - c.rank;
    }
    /** Returns a negative number if this object is lower in rank than c,
     *   0 if the cards are equal rank, and a positive number if this object
     *   is higher in rank than c. Aces are considered 'high'.
     */
    public String toString(){
        return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit];
    }
    public boolean equals(Card c) {
        return rank == c.rank && suit == c.suit;
    }
}

public class Deck{
    private ArrayList<Card> cards;
    /**
       * Create 52 cards.
       */
    public Deck(){

        cards= new ArrayList<Card>();

        for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
             for(int j=2;j<14;j++){
                 cards.add(new Card(suits[i],ranks[j])); 

             }
         }
    }

    //add a card at the end
    public void add(Card c){
        cards.add(c);
    }

    //get the top card 
    public Card getTopCard(){
        return cards.remove(0);
    }
    /**
        * Returns the number of cards in the hand.
        */
    public int getCardsCount(){
        return cards.size();
    }
    //clear the deck
    public void clear(){
        cards.clear();
    }
    //shuffle
    public void shuffle(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i<2000; i++){  //repeat 2000 times
            if (cards.size() > 0){
                Card topCard = cards.remove(0);
                int newPosition = rand.nextInt(cards.size());
                cards.add(newPosition, topCard);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Deck supposed to be an inner class? Right now it tries to access `suits` and `ranks`. Both are not visible.

Comment: I donot know about inner class, Should I use aggregation or inheritance on this program?